# Polymorph magical item

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, balance, polymorph

I have a Warlock and I wanted it to be able to cast self-cast Polymorph. I wanted guidance to be able to show my DM a base item that would be able to do that so we can work on it.

My question really is:
For an Item that only self-casts polymorph, with attunement, what would be the rarity level of it and how much charges and reload time for them should it have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### A self-cast Wand of Polymorph would be Rare.

As far as charges and recharge, just copy from the Wand of Polymorph, which is Very Rare, and restricting it to self-targeting reduces its utility a bit, so call it Rare.

Comment: Thank you! We were not aware of the [Wand of Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4796-wand-of-polymorph).